# Installing ROSAria in ROS Kinetic

Tags: rosaria

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am trying to install the ROSAria package in my ROS Kinetic using the following [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSARIA/Tutorials/How%20to%20use%20ROSARIA#Bring_ROSARIA_into_the_workspace). While building my package using catkin_make, I get the following error:
From what I understand, it is throwing an error because it cannot find -lAria. Please help.

```
Base path: /home/jugesh/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/jugesh/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/jugesh/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/jugesh/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/jugesh/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/jugesh/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j8 -l8" in "/home/jugesh/catkin_ws/build"
####
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 13%] Built target listener
[ 26%] Built target talker
[ 26%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 26%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 26%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 26%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 26%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 26%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 33%] Built target rosaria_gencfg
[ 33%] Built target _rosaria_generate_messages_check_deps_BumperState
[ 40%] Built target rosaria_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 46%] Built target rosaria_generate_messages_cpp
[ 53%] Built target rosaria_generate_messages_lisp
[ 66%] Built target rosaria_generate_messages_py
[ 80%] Built target rosaria_generate_messages_eus
[ 80%] Built target rosaria_gencpp
[ 80%] Built target rosaria_generate_messages
[ 86%] Linking CXX executable /home/jugesh/catkin_ws/devel/lib/rosaria/RosAria
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/Aria/lib/libAria.so when searching for -lAria
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lAria
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
rosaria/CMakeFiles/RosAria.dir/build.make:152: recipe for target '/home/jugesh/catkin_ws/devel/lib/rosaria/RosAria' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/jugesh/catkin_ws/devel/lib/rosaria/RosAria] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2727: recipe for target 'rosaria/CMakeFiles/RosAria.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [rosaria/CMakeFiles/RosAria.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250235/installing-rosaria-in-ros-kinetic/) by [ClarkGrissom](https://answers.ros.org/users/28830/clarkgrissom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-12-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are running a 64-bit OS, make sure that you have the 64-bit ARIA library installed (libaria amd64 package).

(I just updated the tutorial to mention this more explicitly.)

---

Originally posted by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) with karma: 821 on 2016-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0